# combining and aggregating two sql tables

Tags: sql

I wrote a sql statement das returns an author, count of negative comments and count of positiv coments.

Example output:

Mike 3 4
Daniel 5 6
Mike 1 3

And I'd like to aggregate Mike so that you have as result Mike 4 7. How can i do this as a sql query?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample data and a query showing what you've tried already?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  Author
,       sum(NegativeComments) as SumNegative
,       sum(PositiveComments) as SumPositive
from    YourTable
group by
        Author
```